# Django DRP post method how to pass arguments

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm new with Django DRF  and i try to pass arguments in my post view

```
class MyTestPost(APIView):
    def post(self, request, name, age):
        if name != 'TestName':
           raise ValidationError('name is incorrect')
           # some additinal logic

       return Response()
```

urls.py

```
path('newTest/', MyTestPost.as_view()),
```

when i try to execute it (I passed argument in body of request) it raise an Error

```
TypeError: post() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'age'
```

How to make it work?

Comment: what is the url of your post? could you please share the `url.py` file too?

Comment: @TusammaSalSabil added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you didn't specify your parameters in url I suppose you pass them in  body of the post request, then you need to check it through *request.data*

```
class MyTestPost(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        if request.data["name"] != 'TestName':
           raise ValidationError('name is incorrect')
           # some additinal logic

       return Response()
```

Also if you want to validate your data DRF has serializers for that task.

Django Rest Framework has amazing official documentations (easy to read), I suggest you to check it and start from:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to pass `name` and `age` as post argument then you have to configure your url as following:**

```
path('newTest/<str:name>/<int:age>/', MyTestPost.as_view()),
```

**Your request url should be as following:**

```
127.0.0.1:8000/newTest/test name/43/
```

> **It's not good practice**

### **Ideal Approach:**

**I am assuming that You a model as following**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, help_text="Person name.")
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10, blank=False, help_text="Person age.")
    # you add other fileds like created_at, updated_at
```

**Define a serializer class:**

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    age = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    # add other model related field
```

**Code a viewset like this:**

```
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Person.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

**Define URL like this:**

```
path('add-person/', PersonViewSet.as_view(), name='add_person'),
```

> **You can follow this kind of structure for better practice**